# Google Data API Query

Tags: ssis, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-data-api

I use the Query https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FileID/export?mimeType=text/tab-separated-values to download Google Sheets. My sheet has different tabs in it. Is there a way that I can download all the tabs in the sheet or a particular sheet with the name? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-download-just-one-sheet-from-Google-spreadsheet), you can download a specific sheet using `gID`. Each sheet has a `gID` and you can find the `gID` of specific sheet in the URL of spreadsheet. You can use this link to download specific sheet `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<KEY>/export?format=xlsx&gid=<GID>`.

Example:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D5vzPaOJOx402RAEF41235qQTOs28_M51ee5glzPzj0/export?format=xlsx&gid=1990092150`

KEY is the unique ID of spreadsheet.

You may also refer with this [thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/58615/export-all-sheets-in-a-spreadsheet-to-csv-in-google-apps) on how to export sheets in a spreadsheet to csv in Google Apps using Google Apps Script.

> Couldn't find any built in way to do it so [I wrote a script](https://www.drzon.net/export-all-google-sheets-to-csv/) to use in Google Sheets
>
> Just paste it in script editor and run
>
> ```
> function onOpen() {
>   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
>   var csvMenuEntries = [{name: "export as csv files", functionName: "saveAsCSV"}];
>   ss.addMenu("csv", csvMenuEntries);
> };
>  
> function saveAsCSV() {
>   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
>   var sheets = ss.getSheets();
>
>   // create a folder from the name of the spreadsheet
>   var folder = DocsList.createFolder(ss.getName().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'_') +'_csv_' + new Date().getTime());
>   for (var i = 0 ; i < sheets.length ; i++) {
>     var sheet = sheets[i];
>     // append ".csv" extension to the sheet name
>     fileName = sheet.getName() + ".csv";
>     // convert all available sheet data to csv format
>     var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName, sheet);
>     // create a file in the Docs List with the given name and the csv data
>     folder.createFile(fileName, csvFile);
>   }
>   Browser.msgBox('Files are waitig in a folder named ' + folder.getName());
> }
>  
> function convertRangeToCsvFile_(csvFileName, sheet) {
>   // get available data range in the spreadsheet
>   var activeRange = sheet.getDataRange();
>   try {
>     var data = activeRange.getValues();
>     var csvFile = undefined;
>  
>     // loop through the data in the range and build a string with the csv data
>     if (data.length > 1) {
>       var csv = "";
>       for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
>         for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
>           if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
>             data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
>           }
>         }
>  
>         // join each row's columns
>         // add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
>         if (row < data.length-1) {
>           csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
>         }
>         else {
>           csv += data[row];
>         }
>       }
>       csvFile = csv;
>     }
>     return csvFile;
>   }
>   catch(err) {
>     Logger.log(err);
>     Browser.msgBox(err);
>   }
> }
> ```